# Downloading File from remote server using php script without fopen

Tags: php, .net-3.5, c#-3.0, download

Scenario : I have a c# .net web page. I want the user to be able to download a file placed on a remote server from a link on my page. However while downloading there should be minimum load on my server. Hence i tried creating a HttpWebRequest instance, passed the download.php path

e.g. 
**HttpWebRequest myHttpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://servername/download.php");**

**myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add
("Content-disposition", "attachment;filename=XXX.pdf");
myHttpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/pdf";**

Passed the httprequest object in the session; however while reading the httpwebresponse on another page the contenttype is reset to "text/html".

Also the php file readers the headers and uses a readfile command to download the file. It gives the following error. **Warning: readfile() [function.readfile]: URL file-access is disabled in the server configuration in**

Comment: Thanks for that info. I have tried altering the scripts. I have added the following in my c# code,i read these headers in the php file and set the headers accordingly. IE responds and loads the file however Chrome and Firefox display binary data. Thanks for that info. I have tried altering the scripts. I have added the following in my c# code myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("DESC", "File Transfer"); myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("DISP", "attachment; filename=cards.jpg"); myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("CONT", "image/jpeg"); myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("ENCODE", "binary");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't entirely understand the scenario, but on PHP side, if `fopen()` URL access is disabled, your next port of call should be the [curl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) family of functions. (Or, of course, activate URL access using the `allow_url_fopen` php.ini option but it sounds like you can't do that.)

The `text/html` header is probably due to the download failing.

A very rudimentary example:

```
 $ch = curl_init();
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
 curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1); 
 $result = curl_exec($ch); // $result will contain the contents of the request
 curl_close($ch);
 ?>
```

Comment: Note that you also won't be able to use `file_get_contents`

Comment: Thanks for that info. I have tried altering the scripts. I have added the following in my c# code,i read these headers in the php file and set the headers accordingly. IE responds and loads the file however Chrome and Firefox display binary data. Thanks for that info. I have tried altering the scripts. I have added the following in my c# code myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("DESC", "File Transfer");
        myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("DISP", "attachment; filename=cards.jpg");
        myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("CONT", "image/jpeg");
        myHttpWebRequest.Headers.Add("ENCODE", "binary");

Answer (score 0):

You can get around `allow_url_fopen` restrictions by using fsockopen. Here's a (rudimentary) implementation:

```
function fsock_get_contents($url) {
    $fp = fsockopen($url, 80, $errno, $errstr, 20);
    if (!$fp) {
        echo "$errstr ($errno)<br />\n";
        return false;
    } else {
        $out = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $out .= "Host: " . parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST) . "\r\n";
        $out .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        $contents = '';
        fwrite($fp, $out);
        while (!feof($fp)) {
            $contents .= fgets($fp, 128);
        } fclose($fp);
        return $contents;
    }
}

echo fsock_get_contents('www.google.com');
```